# Как правильно: поднял, отвел, выставил или вытянул?

Tags: выбор-слов

*Став на обочине, он **поднял (выставил, отвел или вытянул)** вбок руку.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***...он отвёл руку в сторону.***

Когда человек отводит или вытягивает руку в сторону (вбок - некрасиво), он обязательно её поднимает до какого-то уровня. Поэтому глаголы *отвёл*, *вытянул*,  думаю, подходят неплохо.